# Multiple query at one Command one Result

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Well i am trying to get the results out of this command it should return something lie
(X) rows affected
Commands Completed Successfully 
Print Statement here

I have no idea how to get those results in a richtextbox..so if anyone out there can help me it would be cool

```
sqlconn.cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS" + ";Initial Catalog=" + shard.Text + ";User ID=" + textBox3.Text + ";Password=" + textBox4.Text);
sqlconn.cnn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM _SiegeFortress Where FortressID LIKE'%[1,3,6]%' INSERT INTO _SiegeFortress (FortressID,GuildID,TaxRatio,Tax,NPCHired,TempGuildID,Introduction,CreatedDungeonTime,CreatedDungeonCount,IntroductionModificationPermission) VALUES (1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,NULL ,NULL ,0 ,1) INSERT INTO _SiegeFortress (FortressID,GuildID,TaxRatio,Tax,NPCHired,TempGuildID,Introduction,CreatedDungeonTime,CreatedDungeonCount,IntroductionModificationPermission) VALUES (3 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,NULL ,NULL ,0 ,1) INSERT INTO _SiegeFortress (FortressID,GuildID,TaxRatio,Tax,NPCHired,TempGuildID,Introduction,CreatedDungeonTime,CreatedDungeonCount,IntroductionModificationPermission) VALUES (6 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,NULL ,NULL ,0 ,1) PRINT 'fewfwef'", sqlconn.cnn);
cmd.Connection = sqlconn.cnn;
SqlDataReader crap;

        try
        {
            crap = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            crap.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Crap");
            SqlDataReader name = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            richTextBox1.Text = name.ToString();
            name.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `DELETE` query doesn't  return any data. There is no point to use `ExecuteReader` with `DELETE` statement.

You need to use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `ExecuteReader`.

From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

```
using(SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    sqlconn.Open();
    richTextBox1.Text = string.Format("{0} rows affected", 
                                      (string)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
}
```

Comment: there's an insert/print statement

Comment: and when i use ExecuteNonQuery it returns an int

Comment: @KhaledMohamed What is `print` statement? o.O Yes `ExecuteNonQuery` returns `int` and you can cast it to `string` as I did.

Comment: you don't get it... lets say i will execute print 'whatever' it should return whatever as a result

Comment: so, any idea @Soner Gönül

Comment: @KhaledMohamed If you need to _return_ something, `ExecuteReader` might be helpful. But you are using `DELETE` statement that **doesn't return** anything.